# What is the fastest method of sampling random values from a Gaussian distribution?

Tags: c#, performance, math, gaussian, sampling

The [Box-Muller transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box%E2%80%93Muller_transform), is an elegant and reasonably performant method of sampling random values from a Gaussian distribution.

I'm looking for a faster method clearly written and in C#.

For reference here's an implementation of the Box-Muller Implementation to act as a baseline for performance comparisons...

```
public class GaussianGenerator
{
    FastRandom _rng = new FastRandom();
    double? _spareValue = null;

    /// <summary>
    /// Get the next sample point from the gaussian distribution.
    /// </summary>
    public double NextDouble()
    {
        if(null != _spareValue)
        {
            double tmp = _spareValue.Value;
            _spareValue = null;
            return tmp;
        }

        // Generate two new gaussian values.
        double x, y, sqr;

        // We need a non-zero random point inside the unit circle.
        do
        {
            x = 2.0 * _rng.NextDouble() - 1.0;
            y = 2.0 * _rng.NextDouble() - 1.0;
            sqr = x * x + y * y;
        }
        while(sqr > 1.0 || sqr == 0);

        // Make the Box-Muller transformation.
        double fac = Math.Sqrt(-2.0 * Math.Log(sqr) / sqr);

        _spareValue = x * fac;
        return y * fac;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Get the next sample point from the gaussian distribution.
    /// </summary>
    public double NextDouble(double mu, double sigma)
    {
        return mu + (NextDouble() * sigma);
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have an elegant implementation of the Ziggurat Algorithm in C#?

Comment: You want speed and elegance ? Implement ratio-of-uniforms ! Ziggurat is (to my mind) ugly and terribly difficult to tune.

Comment: @Alexadre. I have spent a couple of days so far writing a version that's as elegant as possible, but yes it's a *lot* more complex than e.g. Box-Muller, especially after optimizations! I have not heard of ratio-of-uniforms, I will look into it, thanks for the pointer.

Comment: Not sure why this was closed - seems like a perfectly valid programming related question to me, i.e. generating gaussian noise is quite a common requirement, as is doing so efficiently/quickly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For the record here's a clearly written implementation, with unit tests:

[ZigguratGaussianDistribution.cs](https://github.com/colgreen/Redzen/blob/master/Redzen/Numerics/Distributions/Double/ZigguratGaussian.cs)

On my Intel Core i7 6700T @ 2.8Ghz (Skylake) I get the following performance results on a single core test (using BenchmarkDotNet):

- Box-Muller: **54.5M samples/sec**
- Ziggurat: **79.5M samples/sec**

So Ziggurat is about 45% faster in those tests.

Both classes use the [Xoshiro256StarStarRandom](https://github.com/colgreen/Redzen/blob/master/Redzen/Random/Xoshiro256StarStarRandom.cs) class from the [Redzen](https://github.com/colgreen/Redzen) library as a source of pseudo-randomness.

Comment: I have corrected all the links. Edit is in the review queue.

Comment: @Xharlie I've editted your edit. Those sourceforge links are older versions of the software that I should probably delete. Everything is now at https://github.com/colgreen/Redzen/tree/master/Redzen/Numerics

Comment: @Xharlie   
In fact there was a bug in that sourceforge version that makes consecutive gaussian values correlated, which becomes apparent if you plot two successive values on an (x,y) cartesian graph.

Comment: @redcalx Awesome. Now I know which is the best version. BTW - the Redzen version contains a comment saying that the RNG is forked in Math.NET but I checked out the Math.NET code base and the XorShift RNG therein is completely different to Redzen's. I guess that the Redzen one is probably the better one to use.

Comment: @Xharlie yeh it was forked and then someone replaced the entire contents of the file with a multiply-and-shift RNG but didn't change the class name!

Comment: The link to the ZigguratGaussianDistribution.cs does not work.

Answer (score 2):

The use of the [ratio-of-uniforms](http://www2.econ.osaka-u.ac.jp/~tanizaki/class/2013/econome3/13.pdf) method is very fast. I do not have a C#-implementation but I used it in Excel VBA and it was 3x faster compared to the Box-Muller approach: 70s for 10 million samples using Box-Muller compared to 20s for 10 million samples using the ratio-of-uniform method.

[image]

good luck.

Answer (score 1):

An implementation of Ziggurat in C:

http://www.seehuhn.de/pages/ziggurat

Also the GSL sources (in C) contain a few implementations of Gaussian random number generators.  Includes the Box-Mueller and ratio methods.

http://gsl.sourcearchive.com/documentation/1.14plus-pdfsg-1/randist_2gauss_8c-source.html

Answer (score 0):

Ziggurat sampling is very fast and memory efficient. For a C/C++ application, you can use the GSL library