# Excel VBA: Implementing Box Muller, Zigurrat and Ratio of Uniforms Algorithm

Tags: excel, vba, algorithm, runtime, stochastic

This is a very specific question mixing up stochastic knowledge and VBA skills. So very exciting!

I'm trying to compare several methods for generating standard, normally distributed numbers given a source of uniformly distributed random numbers. Therefore I'm implementing the [Box Muller Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box%E2%80%93Muller_transform), [Ziggurat Algorithm](http://cis.poly.edu/~mleung/CS909/s04/Ziggurat.pdf) and [Ratio of Uniforms Algorithm](http://www2.econ.osaka-u.ac.jp/~tanizaki/class/2013/econome3/13.pdf). Every single implementation works great in terms of generating a clean standard, normally distribution. (checked by [Shapiro-Wilk-Test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shapiro%E2%80%93Wilk_test)).

What I want to find out: **which is the quickest method**?

Testing every single program with a total of 10^7 generated numbers these are the run times:

**Box-Muller: 3,7 seconds

Ziggurat: 1,28 seconds

Ratio of Uniforms: 10,77 seconds**

Actually I am very happy about those readings, because I didn't expect it to be that fast. Of course the run time of every single method depends as well on my programm-skills and VBA knowledge.

**My problem**: after doing some research I found out that the Ratio of Uniforms Algorithm should be the quickest (about 3 to 4 times quicker than Box Muller). This information just leans on this [stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7183229/what-is-the-fastest-method-of-sampling-random-values-from-a-gaussian-distributio):

[image]

I am curious **if this is just a wrong claim** of this user or (what I do expect more) **if my code is not perfectly implemented**. Therefore I'll post my code and hope someone could help me with my question, if my code is just not good enough or if the Ratio of Uniforms just doesn't work that quick as mentioned.

```
Sub RatioUniforms()

Dim x(10000000) As Double
Dim passing As Long
Dim amount As Long: amount = 10000000
Dim u1 As Double
Dim u2 As Double
Dim v2 As Double

    Do While passing <= amount
        Do
            u1 = Rnd    'rnd= random number(0,1)
        Loop Until u1 <> 0  'u1 musn't become 0
        v2 = Rnd
        u2 = (2 * v2 - 1) * (2 * exp(-1)) ^ (1 / 2)
        If u1 ^ 2 <= exp(-1 / 2 * u2 ^ 2 / u1 ^ 2) Then
            x(passing) = u2 / u1
            passing = passing + 1
        End If
    Loop

 End Sub
```

Thank you very much helping me on this toppic. Maybe some of you have tried those algorithms in VBA or other languages and can help me with there experience about the run time? If you need something else to know about my other implementations just let me know. Have a great day!

Comment: Since your code works, this might be better asked at Code Review.

Comment: Oh! Never heard of that. Thank you!

Comment: You may try changing the first do while to be a for next loop from 0 to 10M

Comment: If I'd use a next loop I would stil need a do while / do until loop so the array x() gets a value for every passing...

Comment: @J.schmidt You've been [bulk editing questions to add `excel-vba` tag](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10592083/j-schmidt?tab=activity&sort=revisions). Please read the [tag's description](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/excel-vba/info). It has been marked for removal and should not be used. Please undo your edits.

Comment: my bad! thanks for reminding.